# Swift4.2 How to save a two dimensional array constructed by "struct" to UserDefautls?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode, userdefaults

I could successfully save array consisted of "struct" which is [structData] to userDefautls by using those code down below.

```swift
    // save [dataCell] encoded to JSON
    func save(_ cellDatas: [cellData]){
        let encoDatas = cellDatas.map{ try? JSONEncoder().encode($0)}
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encoDatas, forKey: "datas")
    }

    // decode JSON array to [cellData]
    func load() -> [cellData]{
        guard let encodedData = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "datas") as? [Data] else {
            return []
        }
        return encodedData.map{try! JSONDecoder().decode(cellData.self, from: $0)}
    }

    // retrieve datas from UD
    func retrieveData() -> [cellData]{
        datas = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "datas") == nil ? initialData : load()
        return datas
    }
```

However, now that I was required to save a two-dimensional array that is [[structData]] so that I tried those code, replacing a few. But it didn't work.

```swift
//     save [dataCell] encoded to JSON
    func saveTableList(_ tableList: [[cellData]]){
        let encoDatas = tableList.map{ try? JSONEncoder().encode($0)}
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encoDatas, forKey: "tableList")
    }

    // decode JSON array to [cellData]
    func loadTableList() -> [[cellData]]{
        guard let encodedData = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "tableList") as? [[Data]] else {
            return []
        }
        return encodedData.map{try! JSONDecoder().decode(cellData.self, from: $0)}
// this $0 has the error that "Cannot convert value of type '[Data]' to expected argument type 'Data'"
//so I tryied this way instead.
//         return encodedData.map{try! JSONDecoder().decode(cellData.self, from: encodedData)}
//but it didn't work properly
    }

    // retrieve datas from UD
    func retrieveTableListData() -> [cellData]{
        datas = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "datas") == nil ? initialData : load()
        return datas
    }
```

How can I encode/decode 2d array that is [[struct]] to JSON and save/load it using userDefautls??

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you encode whole 2D array at once rather than creating array of encoded objects. I tried this and it worked.

```
  func saveTableList(_ tableList: [[cellData]]) {
    guard let encodedCellData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(tableList) else {
        print("Error")
        return
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedCellData, forKey: "tableList")
}

func loadTableList() -> [[cellData]] {
    guard let encodedCellData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "tableList") as? Data,
        let cellData = try? JSONDecoder().decode([[cellData]].self, from: encodedCellData) else {
            return []
    }
    return cellData
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I will try your way!